# Is running a transaction followed by php code and then a commit atomical in neo4j-php-client?

Tags: php, neo4j, transactions, graphaware

Is the run query in the second code line part of the atomical transaction, or in other words: is it possible that another thread runs a query successfully between the 2nd and 4th line of the following code?

```
$tx = $client->transaction();
$result = $tx->run('CREATE (n:Person) SET n.name = {name} RETURN id(n)', ['name' => 'Michal']);
$tx->push('CREATE (n:Person) RETURN id(n)');
$results = $tx->commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is thread safe and shares nothing between threads.

So no, it is not possible that another thread will run a query in the same transaction as the one opened by the current thread, it will rather use its own transaction.

Comment: But one gets a result back immediately in line 2, even before commiting, which means that if I don't commit then it'll block every other request from other threads, for at least until a specific timeout is reached, is that what you were trying to say?

Comment: You probably didn't understand my question correctly. I know each thread would have its own transaction, but a transaction object here can run a query WITHOUT commiting. Now is this query that wasn't part of the commited transaction BUT used by the transaction object, directly followed by the commited part, or can there be usage of the database in the time interval between the not commited part and the commited part? Thanks.

Comment: I understood very well. You are talking about transaction scope and locking. So if you attempt to write in a transaction, it will try to hold a lock until the transaction is comitted. All changes happening in that transaction are not visible to other transactions until the lock is released. This has nothing to do with php, but with how neo4j works

Comment: Thanks for the answer.